# Using Grep function with for loop

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm having a problem with my code. This works for other values when the ID values are all in the tag matrix, however, if there's a value in the ID that's not in the tag matrix I get the error:

```
Error in IDintag[i] <- grep(ID[i], tag) : replacement has length zero
```

Thanks in advance

```
tag=NULL
ID=NULL

url <- readLines("http://www.afip.gob.ar/contacto")
tag <- as.matrix(grep("</strong>",url))
ID <- grep("correo",url)

for(i in 1:length(ID))
    {IDintag[i] <- grep(ID[i],tag)
    }
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to get as the result?  You can probably use package XML for this

Comment: @RichardScriven I'm trying to get the number in the tag matrix where the row number occurs

Comment: Are you looking for `which(tag %in% ID)`?  Please add the desired result to your post.  It's not clear what you're trying to do

Comment: @RichardScriven  So I have that  

    > ID
    [1] 392 398 423 436 452 466

    > tag
      [,1]
 [1,]  285
 [2,]  296
 [3,]  392
 [4,]  423
 [5,]  436
 [6,]  446
 [7,]  460
 [8,]  482
 [9,]  520
[10,]  541
[11,]  546
[12,]  578
[13,]  589
[14,]  600
[15,]  616


I want the resulting matrix to be

    >IDintag
    [1] 3  4  5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for a loop, you can use `%in%` with `which()`

```
url <- readLines("http://www.afip.gob.ar/contacto")
tag <- as.matrix(grep("</strong>",url))
ID <- grep("correo", url)

matrix(which(tag %in% ID))
#      [,1]
# [1,]    3
# [2,]    4
# [3,]    5
```